# View is not update when using ControllerAs and custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I cannot seem to understand what is going on here. When using the 'this' keyword my view does not update on the button click, however; If I use "scope" it updates correctly. I'm not sure if I did something wrong in my custom directive.

```
//My custom directive
app['directive']('myCustomDirective',function(){

return{
   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl: 'templates/someTemplate.html',
   controller: 'mainCtrl',
   controllerAs: 'ctrl'
}
```

})

```
//My controller, will not update view on click
app['controller']('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {

    this['name'] ='Hello';

    this['click'] = function(){

       this['name'] = '';
     }
})

//Portion of HTML from view.
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name" required/>
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="ctrl.click()">Submit</md-button>


//However; if I use the scope (like below) it will update the view
app['controller']('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
   scope['name'] ='';

   this['click'] = function(){

   scope['name'] = "You entered your name";
   }
})

//Will update the update the view on button click.
<input type="text" ng-model="name" required/>
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="ctrl.click()">Submit</md-button>
```

Comment: `ng-model="ctrl.name"` you got `controllerAs ctrl` on the example that doesn't work? @drivers34

Comment: I'm not sure that    `controller: 'mainCtrl',
   controllerAs: 'ctrl'` is ok with a directive. You should use component for your need

Comment: No it doesn't work, when using the 'this' keyword, however; when I bind to the "scope" it works with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should care about when you are using **this** keyword in javascript. Because this refer to context of current scope and when you use **this** in a function it is not the same with **this** of controller.

That is why you will see all examples of controller as syntax starts with

```
var ctrl = this;
```

So if you set **this** to a variable at start and use that variable as an alias of **this** you will get the result you want...

```
app['controller']('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.name ='Hello';

    ctrl.click= function(){
       ctrl.name = '';
     }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `this` instead of `$scope`, you must write the controller like this:

```
app['controller']('mainCtrl', ['$scope', mainCtrl]);

function mainCtrl ($scope) {
    // here is your code
}
```

If your code inside controller will be more complex, the good practice is to define `var that = this;` and use `that` instead of `this` in children levels.

You can also use `mainCtrl.yourProperty`

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz Wrong? Why? It works fine and i didn't have any problems with this construction yet. I use `angular.module('moduleName').controller('ControllerName', [ControllerName]);` and it's OK

Comment: and then, of course `function ControllerName() {...};`

Comment: It's ok, cheers)
If someone still doubts, here is the style guide from John Papa, he uses this construction https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#getters

Comment: I read John Papa's style guide about this, however; does this work when controllAs is set on the directive's object? It works if the "controllerAs" syntax is set on the view (as in John Papa) example.